# Digital Warrant in Corda

Tags: blockchain, corda, smartcontracts

just like issuing currency or tokens on the ledger i want to issue a digital warrant like an invoice who's owner should be changed, is that possible in Corda.I came across Asset interfaces and commercial paper but they were very confusing.Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible! You can change the owner with any state type. You probably want to use a linear state with two participants; the invoice payer and the invoice payer. Look at the obligation example for how you might do this. See https://www.corda.net/develop/samples.html

Comment: What do you mean by a "warrant" in this case? As in, a warrant to buy shares?Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Roger. I went through this Obligation sample but it's like an advanced IOU. I didn't find any Warrant like multi-parameter object created or issued. I could be wrong; it would be great if you could correct me in case I am.

Comment: Hey Roger, to put the case in another way will be, let say Party A and B are transacting with a commodity and B issues a Warrant (kind of Escrow) on successful reception of commodity in the name of A.
Now A changes the ownership to Party C in the warrant and gives it to C for a token/currency. Now C can further change the ownership in the warrant  to any other party or get the commodity from B.
Hope this make it more clear.
So do you know any ways that to issue this kind of warrant or Escrow document.